# Return id when id value does not equal 0 at least once

Tags: sql

I have 2 tables.

table_1

```
id | product
1  | a
2  | b
3  | c 
4  | d
```

table_2

```
product_id | value
1   | 0
2   | 0
1   | 5
2   | 0
4   | 10
```

How can I return details from table_1 for ids that:

```
- are present in table_2 (table_1.id = table_2.product_id)
- do not have any associated value equal to 0 (for example id "1" should be excluded)
```

The correct result would be id "4" as none of its values equal to zero.

I have tried below query but it returns also id "3" that is not present in the table_2.

```
SELECT * FROM table_1
WHERE id NOT IN (
SELECT product_id FROM table_2
WHERE value = 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use two conditions:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM table_1 t1 
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM table_2 t2
              WHERE t1.id = t2.product_id
             ) AND
      NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM table_2 t2
              WHERE t1.id = t2.product_id AND t2.value = 0
             );
```

Answer (score 1):

The naive approach:

```
-- Step 1: Select product IDs to ignore
SELECT product_id
FROM table_2
WHERE value = 0

-- Step 2: Select product IDs to include
SELECT product_id
FROM table_2
WHERE product_id NOT IN ( -- Use the result of Step 1
    SELECT product_id
    FROM table_2
    WHERE value = 0
)

-- Final query: Select products
SELECT *
FROM table_1
WHERE product_id IN ( -- Use the result of Step 2
    SELECT product_id
    FROM table_2
    WHERE product_id NOT IN ( -- Use the result of Step 1
        SELECT product_id
        FROM table_2
        WHERE value = 0
    )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

One option, using aggregation:

```
SELECT
    t1.id,
    t1.product
FROM table_1 t1
INNER JOIN table_2 t2
    ON t1.id = t2.product_id
GROUP BY
    t1.id,
    t1.product
HAVING
    COUNT(CASE WHEN t2.value = 0 THEN 1 END) = 0;
```

In order for the `HAVING` clause to return true, the product must not have had any zero value in the second table.  Also, the inner join filters off any product which does not appear at all in the second table.

Comment: The COUNT counts all t2.values. Do you mean SUM?

Comment: @jarlh The `CASE` expression which I am counting has an implicit `ELSE` condition, whose value is `NULL`.  `COUNT` does _not_ count `NULL`.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the ids you need to use for the IN clause, by grouping by product_id and putting the condition in the HAVING clause:

```
SELECT * FROM table_1
WHERE id IN (
  SELECT product_id 
  FROM table_2
  GROUP BY product_id
  HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN value = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0
)
```